# Noscript redirect

Tags: javascript, html

Где лучше разместить содержимое `<noscript>`, в `<head></head>` или оставить как есть внизу `<body>` ,чтобы не было проблем с ботами поисковых систем ?

```
<body>
   <!-- your content here... -->
   <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/r.php"></noscript>
</body>
```

Comment: noscript  должен быть там где должно быть его содержимое, в данном случае тэг meta должен быть в head

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения поисковых систем, размещение содержимого `<noscript>` внутри `<head>` или внизу `<body>` не имеет большого значения, поскольку поисковые роботы не выполняют JavaScript и не учитывают содержимое `<noscript>` при индексации сайта. Они сканируют только статический HTML-код страницы.

Однако если посмотреть с точки зрения семантики и удобства разработки, обычно рекомендуется размещать `<noscript>` внутри `<head>`, так как это позволяет более явно указать альтернативное содержимое для пользователей без JavaScript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Метатеги, стили и другие ресурсы -->
  <noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/r.php">
  </noscript>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Ваш контент здесь... -->
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Этот способ позволяет разработчикам легче управлять всеми элементами `<head>`, включая `<noscript>`, и делает код более читаемым и структурированным.